# Replacing a string inside of a list with another string

Tags: python

I am working on a problem where I have to read a file then replace all the occurrences of a string, with another string, then save the file to some other path. I think I can  figure out the saving the file part, I'm just having trouble replacing the string. This is what I have so far.

```
arr = ['This parrot is no more. \n', 'It has ceased to be. \n', "It's expired and gone to meet its maker. \n"]
G = 'This'
B = 'B'

for x in arr:
  y = x.split(' ')
  for i in y:
    i.replace(G,B)
    print(i)
```

The replace doesn't do anything, which doesn't make sense to me since when I do `type()` on the `i` it tells me its a string, and the replace is a string method.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `i = i.replace(G, B)`

Answer (score 3):

Here you are changing a temporary copy of each element, not the actual list. Hence the changes are made in i not the actual list of sentences.

> ```
> for x in arr:
>     y = x.split(' ')
>     for i in y:
>         i.replace(G,B)
> print(i)
> ```
>
> You should follow index based approach i.e

```
arr = ['This parrot is no more. \n', 'It has ceased to be. \n',]
G = 'This'
B = 'B'
for i in range(len(arr)):
      arr[i].replace(G,B)
print (are)
```

Hope this helps
I am sorry for indentation problems since I am using a smartphone right now.

Comment: This will replace `Thistle` with `Btle` which I'm pretty sure is not what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `str.replace` in this scenario as it can have unintended consequences like replacing `Thistle` with `Btle` when you only mean to replace `This` with `B`. Instead, compare the words and replace on a match:

```
out = [' '.join([B if y == G else y for y in x.split()]) for x in arr]
```

Alternatively you can use a regex, adding word boundaries around the string to be replaced:

```
import re
out = [re.sub(r'\b' + G + r'\b', B, x) for x in arr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not saving the result. Also you don't need to split `x`.

```
x = 'This parrot is no more. \n'
x = x.replace('This', 'B')
print(x, end='')  # -> B parrot is no more.
```

Comment: Might be better to handle word boundaries (I guess he wants to replace words).

Comment: @Austin Personally I would use regex, `re.sub(r'\bThis\b', 'B', x)`